# Google APIs: Refreshed access_token only works when refresh_token is also provided in the credentials

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, access-token, refresh-token

Google Python api invocation fails when the supplied credentials instance has a refreshed access_token (along with google clientid/secret). I am finding that I need to provide the refresh_token as well for the call to work. I should mention here that the access_token alone without the refresh_token works fine when the access_token was procured right after authentication. The authorization failure with the access-token alone only occurs after it has been refreshed.

Is this a bug or a feature. It seems to me that the access_token should have worked by itself.

Here's how I refresh the access_token:

```
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(token=None, refresh_token=refresh_token, id_token=None, token_uri=token_uri,client_id=goog_client_id, client_secret=goog_client_sec, scopes=SCOPES)
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
access_token = credentials.token
```

Here's how I set up credentials and invoke the service:

```
creds = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(token=access_token, refresh_token=refresh_token, id_token=None, token_uri=token_uri,client_id=goog_client_id, client_secret=goog_client_sec, scopes=SCOPES)
user_info_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('oauth2', 'v2', credentials=creds)
user_info = user_info_service.userinfo().get().execute()
```

I expected the access_token by itself to be  adequate to make the api call.The refresh_token should not have been required. However, this is not the case.